# HTML form with side by side input fields

Tags: html, css, forms

I have a html form that is basically vertical but i really have no idea how to make two text fields on the same line. For example the following form below i want the First and Last name on the same line rather then one below the other.

```
    <form action="/users" method="post"><div style="margin:0;padding:0">


            <div>
                <label for="username">First Name</label>
                <input id="user_first_name" name="user[first_name]" size="30" type="text" />

            </div>

            <div>
                <label for="name">Last Name</label>
                <input id="user_last_name" name="user[last_name]" size="30" type="text" />
            </div>
            <div>
                <label for="email">Email</label>
                <input id="user_email" name="user[email]" size="30" type="text" />
            </div>
            <div>
                <label for="pass1">Password</label>
                <input id="user_password" name="user[password]" size="30" type="password" />
            </div>
            <div>
                <label for="pass2">Confirm Password</label>

                <input id="user_password_confirmation" name="user[password_confirmation]" size="30" type="password" />

            </div>
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The default display style for a div is "block." This means that each new div will be under the prior one.

You can:

Override the flow style by using float as @Sarfraz suggests.

or

Change your html to use something other than divs for elements you want on the same line. I suggest that you just leave out the divs for the "last_name" field

```
<form action="/users" method="post"><div style="margin:0;padding:0">
  <div>
    <label for="username">First Name</label>
    <input id="user_first_name" name="user[first_name]" size="30" type="text" />

    <label for="name">Last Name</label>
    <input id="user_last_name" name="user[last_name]" size="30" type="text" />
  </div>
  ... rest is same
```

Answer (score 25):

Put `style="float:left"` on each of your divs:

```
<div style="float:left;">...........
```

**Example:**

```
<div style="float:left;">
  <label for="username">First Name</label>
  <input id="user_first_name" name="user[first_name]" size="30" type="text" />
</div>

<div style="float:left;">
  <label for="name">Last Name</label>
  <input id="user_last_name" name="user[last_name]" size="30" type="text" />
</div>
```

To put an element on new line, put this div below it:

```
<div style="clear:both;">&nbsp;</div>
```

Of course, you can also create classes in the CSS file:

```
.left{
  float:left;
}

.clear{
  clear:both;
}
```

And then your html should look like this:

```
<div class="left">
  <label for="username">First Name</label>
  <input id="user_first_name" name="user[first_name]" size="30" type="text" />
</div>

<div class="left">
  <label for="name">Last Name</label>
  <input id="user_last_name" name="user[last_name]" size="30" type="text" />
</div>
```

To put an element on new line, put this div below it:

```
<div class="clear">&nbsp;</div>
```

**More Info:**

- [CSS Float Clear Tutorial](http://css.maxdesign.com.au/floatutorial/)

Comment: Or better still create a class that has float:left as part of it's definition.

Comment: @Dan Diplo: Done before seeing this comment :)

Comment: you can also just move the second label and input field into the same div as the first one - if you're not doing vertical separation then there's no need to separate them into individual divs, thus negating the need for a float clear underneath.

Comment: @hollsk: That is good idea but individual class will allow him to position his elements at accurate places by using floats. It is up to OP though.

Comment: Agreed - it always depends on you're actually trying to achieve with the layout. Personally I'd rather use a span than a div in these cases simply because that's what they're designed for; if you don't want to have block rendering behaviour then don't use a block element in the first place. As always, though, there's many different ways to skin this particular cat.

Answer (score 5):

For the sake of bandwidth saving, we shouldn't include `<div>` for each of `<label>` and `<input>` pair

This solution may serve you better and may increase readability

```
<div class="form">
            <label for="product_name">Name</label>
            <input id="product_name" name="product[name]" size="30" type="text" value="4">
            <label for="product_stock">Stock</label>
            <input id="product_stock" name="product[stock]" size="30" type="text" value="-1">
            <label for="price_amount">Amount</label>
            <input id="price_amount" name="price[amount]" size="30" type="text" value="6.0">
</div>
```

The css for above form would be

```
.form > label
{
  float: left;
  clear: right;
}

.form > input
{
  float: right;
}
```

I believe the output would be as following:

[image: Demo]

Answer (score 2):

I would go with Larry K's solution, but you can also set the display to **inline-block** if you want the benefits of both block and inline elements.

You can do this in the div tag by inserting:

```
style="display:inline-block;"
```

Or in a CSS stylesheet with this method:

```
div { display:inline-block; }
```

Hope it helps, but as earlier mentioned, I would personally go for Larry K's solution ;-)

Answer (score 2):

You should put the input for the last name into the same div where you have the first name.

```
<div>
    <label for="username">First Name</label>
    <input id="user_first_name" name="user[first_name]" size="30" type="text" />
    <input id="user_last_name" name="user[last_name]" size="30" type="text" />
</div>
```

Then, in your CSS give your #user_first_name and #user_last_name height and float them both to the left. For example:

```
#user_first_name{
    max-width:100px; /*max-width for responsiveness*/
    float:left;
}

#user_lastname_name{
    max-width:100px;
    float:left;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use the {display: inline-flex;}
this would produce this:
[inline-flex](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KZFYp.png)