# How to arrange html label and input side by side

Tags: html, css

I have this few line of `html` code i want to arrange the `label` and `input` side by side with the `label` on top of the `input` with `css` but am not able to work around it. I found similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3488447/html-form-with-side-by-side-input-fields)which suggest use of `display:inline-block;` to achieve that but after including it in my code an not able to do it.

```css
body {
  background-color: red;
}

input[type=text] {
  border: 2px solid black;
  border-radius: 4px;
  margin-left: 150px;
  display: inline-block;
  clear: both;
}

input[type=number] {
  border: 2px solid black;
  border-radius: 4px;
  margin-left: 150px;
  display: inline-block;
  clear: both;
}
```

```html
<div id=tk>
  <form action="" , method="">
    <div id="styleform">
      <label for="NAME">&nbsp&nbsp FIRST NAME</label></br>
      <input type="text" id="NAME" size="20"></br>
      </br>
      <label for="no">&nbsp&nbsp NUMBER</label></br>
      <input type="number" id="no" , size="45"></br>
      </br>
      <label for="age">&nbsp&nbsp AGE</label></br>
      <input type="number" id="age" size="45"></br>
      </br>
      <label for="S_NO:">&nbsp&nbsp CODE</label></br>
      <input type="text" id="S_NO:" size="20"></br>
      </br>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

I think this kind of easy question for some of you this new be in `web development`

This how i want it to look like

[image: example]

Comment: `<br>` = line break != side by side

Comment: Can you explain this sentence `i want to arrange the label and input side by side with the label on top of the input` it contradict itself. label and input side by side or label on top of input?

Comment: want to have the `input` side by side the position the label on top

Comment: Look at the other question again, the html is different. You have to wrap the label and input in a div and set that div to display inline-block, you are missing the wrap

Comment: Possible duplicate of [HTML form with side by side input fields](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3488447/html-form-with-side-by-side-input-fields)

Comment: I marked your question as a duplicate because if you look at the other question link in your own post, you will see the html difference which should solve your problem. It looks like no one really looked at the other question before commenting or answering

Comment: @Huangism.  Perhaps, but my answer attempted to address, what I perceived as, other issues with the OPs code as well.

Comment: @LAS I see numerous errors in your code.  I would suggest continuing to practice your HTML and start running your code through a validator, such as https://validator.w3.org/check.  BTW, another issue was your first div, it should have quotes around the name of the ID.

Comment: Thanks for all the corrections and your suggestion on my `code`  have edited the question with image attached.

Comment: @LAS, please see this updated FIDDLE: https://jsfiddle.net/Lu5k1yk8/4/

Comment: @user2796515 i want two `input` on each row `two input on top and two below`

Comment: @LAS I have updated fiddle again, please see updated answer.

Answer (score 3):

**UPDATE**

Updated fiddle after image provided

@LAS You are inserting line breaks, that is part of the problem.  I have created this fiddle, fixing several things: https://jsfiddle.net/Lu5k1yk8/6/

- Added ; after your spaces
- fixed the line breaks (I believe the syntax should be `<br>` or `<br />`, not `</ br>` and removed them after labels
- Changed your CSS for the textboxes to inline-table
- Increased width of labels so they do not create new lines

Also, I would suggest not using spaces (`nbsp;`) or `<br />`'s and instead using CSS to create the correct spaces and line breaks.

Here is a good demonstration of how to use padding and margins: http://www.digizol.com/2006/12/margin-vs-padding-css-properties.html

Comment: this not what i am looking for have edited the question with an image to depicts

Comment: i want two `input` on each row `two input on top and two below`

Comment: Why are you using ```clear: both``` if there's no `float` anywhere.

Comment: @elena, not sure if this is directed at me or OP, for mine it is leftover from original CSS and has no affect, I removed it on https://jsfiddle.net/Lu5k1yk8/6/

Comment: @user2796515 The fiddle that you linked in the answer is version 5 and it still contains it.

Comment: @elena. Fixed fiddle in answer.

Answer (score 0):

Just remove **br** tag and add this to your code

```
 input[type="text"] + label {
           display: inline;
    }
```

Comment: this not what i am looking for have edited the question with an image to depicts

Answer (score 0):

I changed your code a bit, I hope this is what you are looking for:

I set `label` into an `inline-block` element and set its `min-width` to `150px`, and removed the `margin-left: 150px;`.

Also, if you use `&nbsp`, you need to add a semicolon at the end of it: `&nbsp;`, and with the `</br>` you need to add the slash at the end: `<br />`

```css
body{
  background-color: red;
}

label {
  display: block;
  min-width: 150px;
}

.test {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 45%;
  background-color: white;
  border: solid 1px blue;
  padding: 5px 10px;
} 

input[type=text] {
  border: 2px solid black;
  border-radius: 4px;
  display: inline-block;
  clear: both;

}

 input[type=number] {
  border: 2px solid black;
  border-radius: 4px;
  display: inline-block;
  clear: both;
}
```

```html
<div id=tk>
      <form action="", method="">

        <div id="styleform">
          <div class="test">
            <label for="NAME" >FIRST NAME</label>
            <input type="text" id="NAME" size="20"><br /><br />
          </div>
          <div class="test">
            <label for="no" >NUMBER</label>
            <input type="number" id="no", size="45"><br /><br />
          </div>
          <div class="test">
            <label for="age" >AGE</label>
            <input type="number" id="age" size="45"><br /><br />
          </div>
          <div class="test">
            <label for="S_NO:" >CODE</label>
            <input type="text" id="S_NO:" size="20"><br /><br />
          </div>
        </div>

        </form>
   </div>
```

**EDIT: ** I have changed the code. Hope this helps you this time ;)

Hope this helps.

Comment: this not what i am looking for have edited the question with an image to depicts

Comment: @LAS I have edited the code looks similar to your screenshot in my opinion. Hopefully, it helps this time.

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way is to take the label and input in a table.enter code here`<table>
<tr><th>label</th><td><input type="text"></td></tr></table>`

Comment: this not what i am looking for have edited the question with an image to depicts

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean something like this?

```css
.block {
  display: block;
}

.inline-block {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 49%;
}

body {
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div id=tk>
  <form action="" method="">
    <div id="styleform">
      <div class="inline-block">
        <label class="block" for="NAME">FIRST NAME</label>
        <input class="block" type="text" id="NAME" size="20">
      </div>
      <div class="inline-block">
        <label class="block" for="no">NUMBER</label>
        <input class="block" type="number" id="no" , size="45">
      </div>
      <div class="inline-block">
        <label for="age" class="block" >AGE</label>
        <input type="number" class="block"  id="age" size="45">
      </div>
      <div class="inline-block">
        <label class="block" for="S_NO:">CODE</label>
        <input type="text" class="block"  id="S_NO:" size="20">
      </div>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```